# How can I input variables into the Tcl switch code block?

Tags: variables, switch-statement, tcl

I am trying to do something very simple, in Tcl 8.5.
I have a variable, and another variable, and I am trying to equate them in a switch. What is very easily done in Python & Ruby, I could not get to work in Tcl. The manual page http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/switch.htm does not help.
See code & results:

```
set k 4
switch 4 {
    $k { puts "yey" }
    default {puts "no recon"  }
}
exit
```

It outputs:

```
no recon
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The first example on the man page shows how to do this, so actually I think it does help, if you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl won't do substitutions within braces. Change your code with double quotes as

```
set k 4
switch 4 "
    $k { puts yey }
    default {puts \"no recon\"  }
"
```

Or write it in a single line as

```
switch 4 $k { puts yey }  default {puts "no recon"  }
```

Comment: or use subst to avoid quoting hell

Comment: The “single-line” version is the right one to use. Put the newlines inside the blocks to run on matching.

Comment: This indeed gets it done, or no quotes, with additional lines backslashes.

Comment: You can use line continuations in the "single-line" version to aid readability